# C++: construct by return within constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have several objects with a C-style constructor:

```
struct MyStruct { int item1; int item2 };
MyStruct construct_struct(int a, int b, int c, ...);
```

And I would like, without totally rearranging code copying and pasting duplicate code, to simply define beneath the structures a C++ style constructor:

```
MyStruct::MyStruct(int a, int b, int c, ...){   
    // in pseudo code
    this = construct_struct(a,b,c,...);
}
```

How can this be done in C++?

Comment: You cannot define a member function without declaring it in the class first

Comment: @NathanOliver of course...

Comment: And if `construct_struct` will create an instance of `MyStruct`, then you have infinite recursion there.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is pseudo code.  There should be no infinite recursion, as I will simply be setting data values after calling the default constructor in the function.  Regardless, I already have it working, and the point of the question is to have one instance of the code, and call it within the constructor.  It should be possible.

Comment: You should not try to set `this` in constructor: it is just a pointer to the object under construction. So the common usage is to call a (possibly private or protected) constructor in the factory function and not the opposite...

Comment: Why not flip it around? Write it such that `construct_struct` can be reduced to `return {a, b, c, ...};` - Then you'll have no code duplication.

Comment: Looks like you need `*this = construct_struct(a,b,c,...);` then.

Comment: @SergeBallesta pseudo code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude please think a bit more outside the box.  The point is to avoid having to re-organize a ton of code. Merely add code so that the C-style construction works in calling code, and I can add the OO-style construction paradigm without impacting anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like, without totally rearranging code copying and pasting duplicate code, to simply define beneath the structures a C++ style constructor

Rather than copying the code, you should move it into the C++ constructor, and then rewrite your C-style constructor to call the C++ one:

```
MyStruct::MyStruct(int a, int b, int c, ...){   
    // the code from construct_struct(a,b,c,...) goes here
}

MyStruct construct_struct(int a, int b, int c, ...) {
    return MyStruct(a, b, c, ...);
}
```

This solves the problem with code duplication, and preserves the C constructor.

Comment: Well, that is the opposite of what I would like to do.

Comment: @bordeo In terms of implementation, it's the opposite; in terms of maintaining the interface, you get the same thing with cleaner code. You could even make `construct_struct` an inline function (optimizer would probably do for you as well).

Comment: This is close to the usual approach I've seen in C bindings for C++ class libraries.

Comment: Right, however, the optimization likely applies to the constructor which calls the function and applies it to `*this`.  I don't see any benefit, other than semantics behind the interface.

Comment: @Scheff so right now, we are looking at C++ bindings for a C-style class.

Comment: @bordeo I am not 100% certain that the compiler would apply [copy elision optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to `*this = ...` assignment.

Comment: @Scheff I don't know why you are speaking in terms of specifics and details.  This is a general level question written in pseudo code. The point is to simply add lines of code to achieve desired functionality, rather than move or rearrange lines of code.  This is a clean dev step, as opposed to a dirty, time consuming, and error prone dev step.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - That's because you can't apply copy elision aggressively to assignment. You must have at least two objects, from and to.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight then I can benchmark and test if this micro optimization achieves any benefit after I get a working state with minimal code changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do what dasblinkenlight [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174248/817643) (even though you should). The approach in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53174246/817643) would also work so long as you object is assignable. For the unlikely case of your object getting a `const` member, or being made unassignable for another reason, I present this for completeness.

You can delegate to the copy/move constructor:

```
MyStruct construct_struct(int a, int b, int c, ...){
}

MyStruct::MyStruct(int a, int b, int c, ...) : MyStruct(construct_struct(a,b,c,...)) {}
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for.  If you can present me with a version of this that impacts performance over copying the code into the constructor (I know you can't), then I will agree with you.  In the meantime, having a functional interface in my namespace is worth more to me than depositing my functions in a struct inside the namespace (which is, more or less, a struct with functions as first class citizens).

Comment: @StoryTelier Math, Physics, Computer Science.  Not Object-Oriented.

Comment: @bordeo - Well, they I'll conserve my strength, if you will. I doubt there's convincing any of you.

Comment: @StoryTelier I think it does not serve OO programming to ignore the fact that functions are inherently static and are first class citizens everywhere their inputs can be provided.   OO programming has the effect of locking things into place.  I don't disagree with it; to draw an analogy: if functions are legos, an OO code base is a piece of furniture carved out of a single piece of wood. I also think a bit of kindness on the part of the OO community would go a long way.  OO languages tend to be very oppressive and inflexible communities on here.

Comment: @bordeo - Writing idiomatic code is not about following paradigms. So whatever critique you may have about any OO community, is moot. I'm not up for discussing it. Idiomatic code is about communicating with those who will read your code after you. Those idioms are as important as the idioms in natural languages. Since you and all your collaborators are essentially in agreement about what you like and don't like, it's pointless to try and convince you about idioms in the community of C++ users at large.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, this is a case of me writing a C++ style struct and constructor, next to several C-style structs and constructors.  Rather than trying to rewrite all the C-style structs and constructors right now, I am interested in duplicating the C++ api without changing anything.  This involves fewer changes to code right now.  So I asked the question, and got all this harassment -- which doesn't incline me to respecting the C++ community, or their "way," which has been falling out of favor for years.

Comment: @bordeo - I feel nothing about any side of this argument. So you need not worry about me feeling better. You only got "harassed" because you felt the need to go into a debate with anyone who suggested something you don't approve of. I presented my answer to the benefit of the entire SO community, not just yours. Had you not prodded me about my agreement with dasblinkenlight, none of this later back and forth would have happened.

Comment: In that case, why the personal question? Why the "should"? The normative commentary was out of line. You attempted to scold me, and we both know this is a question of idiom and semantics rather than an objective standard, such as performance.  The upvote you have is from me, by the way.

Comment: @bordeo - The "should" is because more programmers would be able to understand your code if it's following well known idioms. That's an advice I wholeheartedly gave to all future readers of this Q&A. Because Q&A's are here for posterity. Since you prodded, the personal question was to establish how likely this communication benefit would affect your team. Your answer told me it won't, so no point discussing communication benefits, is there? Everything else is just matching the tone you seem intent on setting.

Comment: I accepted your question, and upvoted your response.  In spirit, I agree with placing these constructors in the structs in the final version of code.  However, it isn't a logical next step for me -- remaining consistent is more important at this stage.  This motivates my question.

Comment: @bordeo - And it's not a bad question. Otherwise it would not have attracted so much attention. Plus, at the end of the day, consistency is another aspect of idiomatic coding. Since you follow the idioms in *your* team. Either way, if you got what you needed, and more than one solution was presented, hopefully this post will help more readers in the future, then SO fulfilled its purpose here. So you'll pardon my distraction at not voting sooner.

Comment: Thank you for saying that.  I just see C++ as, in the future, a dominant **multi-paradigm** language.  Also a dominant GPU programming language. But I also see it dying out if this multi-paradigm approach is rejected by the community, or idioms are enforced too strongly (unlike in python, for example).  I say this because I think C# + F#, Java + Scala, Python: these languages will out compete C++ in OO programming; whereas C++ shines in its flexibility.

Comment: That's where my tone came from. I am afraid it will become the next Fortran.

Comment: @bordeo - Then we have quite a bit in common. If I sounded too zealous I apologize. It's just that notion of tying initializtion and deinitialization to object lifetime is IMO very good. It's a thing C++ got very much correct, since a c'tor or d'tor must be called at lifetime boundary, if you stick to c'tors you won't get half baked objects. That's why I advocate so strongly for it. It's not a hill to die on of course. You raised good points too.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

```
MyStruct construct_struct(int a, int b, int c, ...){
}
MyStruct::MyStruct(int a, int b, int c, ...){
    *this = construct_struct(a,b,c,...);
}
```

Comment: Refrain if you can. This will involve a copy of the struct or at best a move. @dasblinkenlight's way is more straightforward and *idiomatic*.